# Derivative of multivariate Gaussian probability density function

Tags: probability, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian

**Question:** We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s^1 \\
\vdots \\
s^k
\end{bmatrix}
\in\mathbb{R}^{kL},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu^1 \\
\vdots \\
\mu^k
\end{bmatrix}
\in\mathbb{R}^{kL},\quad
\Sigma^k\in\mathbb{R}^{kL\times kL}
$$
where $s^t\in\mathbb{R}^L$, $\mu^t\in\mathbb{R}^L$, and $t\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. We have the probability density function denoted by
$$
\mathcal{N}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
s^1 \\
\vdots \\
s^k
\end{bmatrix};
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu^1 \\
\vdots \\
\mu^k
\end{bmatrix},
\Sigma^k
\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{det}(2\pi\Sigma^k)}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
s^1 \\
\vdots \\
s^k
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu^1 \\
\vdots \\
\mu^k
\end{bmatrix}
\right)^\top
(\Sigma^k)^{-1}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
s^1 \\
\vdots \\
s^k
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu^1 \\
\vdots \\
\mu^k
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\right)
.
$$
What is the derivative (Jacobian) of
$$
\nabla_{s^t}
\mathcal{N}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
s^1 \\
\vdots \\
s^k
\end{bmatrix};
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu^1 \\
\vdots \\
\mu^k
\end{bmatrix},
\Sigma^k
\right),
$$
where $t\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. Thanks.

**Attempt:** I am able to derive this for the simpler case of just $\mathcal{N}(s;\mu,\Sigma)$, where $s\in\mathbb{R}^L$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^L$, and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{L\times L}$, where
$$
\mathcal{N}(s;\mu,\Sigma)
=\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(s-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(s-\mu))}{\sqrt{\text{det}(2\pi\Sigma)}}.
$$
For this simple case, we have
$$
\nabla_{s}\mathcal{N}(s;\mu,\Sigma)
=\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-s)\mathcal{N}(s;\mu,\Sigma).
$$
How do I do it for the more complicated case shown above?

Comment: Are you missing a factor of $-\frac{1}{2}$ in the probability density function? Otherwise the integral is infinity.

Comment: Yup, you are right, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the notation
$$\vec{s} = \begin{bmatrix}s^1\\\vdots\\s^k\end{bmatrix}\qquad \vec{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu^1\\\vdots\\s^k\end{bmatrix} \qquad \vec{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma^{1,1} &\dots &\Sigma^{1,k}\\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\\Sigma^{k,1} & \dots & \Sigma^{k,k}\end{bmatrix}$$
The gradient with respect to $[s^1, \dots, s^k]$ of the complicated case is exactly equal to the simple case,
$$\nabla_{s^1, \dots, s^k}\mathcal{N}(\vec{s}; \vec{\mu}, \vec{\Sigma}) = \vec{\Sigma}^{-1}(\vec{\mu} - \vec{s}) \mathcal{N}(\vec{s}; \vec{\mu}, \vec{\Sigma})$$
This is a vector with dimension $kL$. The component in direction $s^t$ is obtained by looking at the entries for $s^t$,
$$ \nabla_{s^t}\mathcal{N}(\vec{s}; \vec{\mu}, \vec{\Sigma}) = \mathcal{N}(\vec{s}; \vec{\mu}, \vec{\Sigma}) \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^k \Pi^{t,i}(\mu^i - s^i)$$
where $\Pi^{i,j}$ is notation for the block matrix
$$ \vec{\Sigma}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\Pi^{1,1} &\dots &\Pi^{1,k}\\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\\Pi^{k,1} & \dots & \Pi^{k,k}\end{bmatrix}.$$